# Disable cancel subscription for a specific product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm working on Woocommerce Subscriptions. This code disables the cancel subscription button on the user account:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Remove Subscription Action Buttons from My Account
 * Plugin URI: https://gist.github.com/thenbrent/8851287/
 * Description: Remove any given button from the <a href="http://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/customers-view/#section-2">My Subscriptions</a> table on the My Account page. By default, only the "Change Payment Method" button is removed, but you can uncomment additional actions to remove those buttons also.
 * Author: Brent Shepherd
 * Author URI:
 * Version: 2.0
 */

/**
 * Remove the "Change Payment Method" button from the My Subscriptions table.
 *
 * This isn't actually necessary because @see eg_subscription_payment_method_cannot_be_changed()
 * will prevent the button being displayed, however, it is included here as an example of how to
 * remove just the button but allow the change payment method process.
 */
function eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button( $actions, $subscription ) {

    foreach ( $actions as $action_key => $action ) {
        switch ( $action_key ) {
            case 'change_payment_method':   // Hide "Change Payment Method" button?
//          case 'change_address':      // Hide "Change Address" button?
//          case 'switch':          // Hide "Switch Subscription" button?
//          case 'resubscribe':     // Hide "Resubscribe" button from an expired or cancelled subscription?
//          case 'pay':         // Hide "Pay" button on subscriptions that are "on-hold" as they require payment?
//          case 'reactivate':      // Hide "Reactive" button on subscriptions that are "on-hold"?
//          case 'cancel':          // Hide "Cancel" button on subscriptions that are "active" or "on-hold"?
                unset( $actions[ $action_key ] );
                break;
            default: 
                error_log( '-- $action = ' . print_r( $action, true ) );
                break;
        }
    }

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', 'eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button', 100, 2 );
```

Original source: https://gist.github.com/thenbrent/8851287

But I'd like to make an exception to this: the cancel button must appear for a specific product (the 1 month subscription product)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

right after your function declaration:

```
function eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button( $actions, $subscription ) {
// etc.
```

add this:

```
function eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button( $actions, $subscription ) {
   $is_my_product = false;
   if ( sizeof( $subscription_items = $subscription->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
     foreach ( $subscription_items as $item_id => $item ) {
         $product = $item->get_product();
         if ( $product->get_id() == 123456 ) {
            $is_my_product = true;
            break;
         }
     }
   }
   if ( $is_my_product ) return $actions;
```

Comment: Clearly, change 123456 with your target product ID

Comment: Thanks, it's working like a charm! I have another question below if you don't mind answering it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi We are using the code below for our website. It was working fine and hiding the "switch" button. But recently we saw that some customer was able to switch and when checked the switch button appears on "myaccount page"
If you notice, we are also hiding "cancel" and thats still working but just switch is showing up. Kindly pls help to determine why its showing up when its suppose to be hidden Thanks!

/**

- Plugin Name: Remove Subscription Action Buttons from My Account
- Plugin URI: https://gist.github.com/thenbrent/8851287/
- Description: Remove any given button from the [My Subscriptions](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/customers-view/#section-2) table on the My Account page. By default, only the "Change Payment Method" button is removed, but you can uncomment additional actions to remove those buttons also.
- Author: Brent Shepherd
- Author URI:
- Version: 2.0
  */

/**

- Remove the "Change Payment Method" button from the My Subscriptions table.
- 
- This isn't actually necessary because @see eg_subscription_payment_method_cannot_be_changed()
- will prevent the button being displayed, however, it is included here as an example of how to
- remove just the button but allow the change payment method process.
  */
  function eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button( $actions, $subscription ) {

  foreach ( $actions as $action_key => $action ) {
  switch ( $action_key ) {
  //          case 'change_payment_method':   // Hide "Change Payment Method" button?
  //          case 'change_address':      // Hide "Change Address" button?
  case 'switch':          // Hide "Switch Subscription" button?
  //          case 'resubscribe':     // Hide "Resubscribe" button from an expired or cancelled subscription?
  //          case 'pay':         // Hide "Pay" button on subscriptions that are "on-hold" as they require payment?
  //          case 'reactivate':      // Hide "Reactive" button on subscriptions that are "on-hold"?
  case 'cancel':          // Hide "Cancel" button on subscriptions that are "active" or "on-hold"?
  unset( $actions[ $action_key ] );
  break;
  default:
  error_log( '-- $action = ' . print_r( $action, true ) );
  break;
  }
  }

  return $actions;
  }
  add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', 'eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button', 100, 2 );

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35586489)